# ACF - programmatically install and activate in pipeline to automate testing for custom plugin development?

Tags: plugin-development, testing, integration-tests

**Original question on SO:** [WP plugin integretion testing - how to enable additional plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76155558/wp-plugin-integretion-testing-how-to-enable-additional-plugins)

##### TL/DR

I'm developing a custom plugin and setting up ci/cd via gitlab pipeline.
Testing and publishing to private package registry works correctly.
Latest requirements have my code rely on 3rd party plugins, i.e. ACF `get_field()`, so now I need to install and activate other plugins in my pipeline testing job to correctly test new functionalities.

##### Is there a way to programmatically install/activate plugins in wp?

It would be optimal via official WP tools, but bash scripts are accepted as well.
Since those plugins are now required to correctly run my code alongside the entire site, if having the zip versioned with my code just to be available during pipeline jobs is ok (even if it would be a pain in the a$$).